# Regex for starting with bracket issue

Tags: regex, node.js

I am using Node.js.  I am using the following regex with text.  It is not catching using regex.

```
 Regex: \b\(CVD\)
 String: (CVD)<span class="ff7">
```

Any issue the above regex with string..

Any one assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\b` captures the transition between non-alphabetic and alphabetic characters. `(` is not an alphabetic character and the `\b` would only match if the character preceeding it *was* so. Such as in the following case: `ABC(CVD)<span ...>`.

Comment: Use `\B\(CVD\)`, or if you create the regex dynamically: `RegExp("(^|\W)" + searchword)` (that will require some more coding if you need to further use the match). `\b` before `(` means there must be a digit/letter/_ symbol before `(`.

Comment: What @Phylogenesis said. Only, to clarify, the transition is between word characters  (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _) and others.